# Openlayers - Image layer's source(Raster) disappears on each zoom

Tags: reactjs, gis, openlayers, wrapper

I'm having a case where I have to create a Hillshading Image layer on top of the original Raster WebGLTileLayer(GeoTIFF source) to show hillshading view. I'm facing an issue where

1. The source tile layer disappears on each zoom as the hillshade Image layer is being rendered.
2. Sometimes, the hillshade is not appearing even when the raster source is given correctly.

Has anyone faced this issue before. If so, can someone help me out.

Comment: How are you producing the hillshading?  WebGL styling as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-shaded-relief.html or using the tilelayer inside a RaterSource as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/shaded-relief.html ?  Can you share your code?

Comment: @Mike I had actually used the second link, but used a WebGLTilelayer(DEM) as a source for the RasterSource. I wasn't aware there was a WebGL example somewhere. 
Maybe using style for this is a better idea. I'm already using a style like heatmap(Blue->Red) for elevation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issues using style instead of tilelayer as raster source, as done here - https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/webgl-shaded-relief.html

Thanks to @Mike 's comment.